# Edid information

Tags: c, linux, bash

Redefining the Question:

Is there any way to get the Serial ID of the connected monitor ?

I want to gather the Edid information of the monitor. I can get it from xorg.0.log file when I run the X with -logverbose option.

But the problem is that If I switch the monitor ( plug-out the current monitor and then plug-in another monitor ), then there is no way to get this information.

Is there any way to get the EDID dynamically ( or runtime ) ? Or any utility/tool which will inform me as soon as monitor is connected and disconnected ?

I am using the LFS-6.4.

Regards,
SHW

Comment: Please see: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this read-edid package.
http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/

Once you have it compiled and installed, you can run these commands:

```
# read-edid | parse-edid
```

This will provide you with an X.org config-like output.
Feel free to hack further.