# Win32 code to get EDID in Windows XP/7

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi, monitor, edid

I found [this](http://www.winvistatips.com/read-monitors-edid-information-t181727.html) page and was unable to get any useful information out of it (it searches the registry for something but never finds it and goes into an infinite loop).

As [this question regarding getting the monitor serial UID ("EDID information")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040686/edid-information) asks I would like the same information but from the point of view of Win32 C code (or C/C++ [DDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_development_kit) code, or whatever) instead of Linux.

Comment: For reference, code for similar task in Mac OS X: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236498/how-to-get-the-display-name-with-the-display-id-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMI didn't support monitor classes in Windows XP.
The documented way of getting the EDID was - and still is - with the Setup API.

Longer survey and a VC++ code sample [are available here](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/).

Comment: How come GetSizeForDevID(const CString& TargetDevID, ...) doesn't use the value of TargetDevID? Did you test this on multi monitor setups or a laptop in non-mirror mode? (e.g. extended desktop mode). Thanks for the link by the way.

Comment: So your recommended method for getting the EDID doesn't work when I extend my desktop; the internal LCD is the only EDID I can retrieve unless I switch to mirroring mode. So my WMI approach though brittle and kind of bassackwards is still superior for my purposes, which is to know the product ID/ manufacturer ID of the connect monitor(s) in both extended or mirrored mode. Which makes me sad since I need a non-WMI approach that works more dependably.

Comment: I take it back, this method does work, with the double while (EnumDisplayDevices(...) loops, when I take out the bFoundDevice parts of the while checks (see my other answer).

Comment: Sorry for the late response - yes, I was interested at the time only in the first valid EDID.

Answer (score 3):

First I got a C# version working using [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572):

```
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
                "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("WmiMonitorID instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                //Console.WriteLine("Active: {0}", queryObj["Active"]);
                Console.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);
                dynamic snid = queryObj["SerialNumberID"];

                Console.WriteLine("SerialNumberID: (length) {0}", snid.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("YearOfManufacture: {0}", queryObj["YearOfManufacture"]);
                dynamic code = queryObj["ProductCodeID"];
                string pcid = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
                {
                    pcid = pcid + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(code[i]);
                    //pcid = pcid +code[i].ToString("X4");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ProductCodeID: " +  pcid);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
```

Below is the C++ code I [found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=VS.85).aspx) and tweaked to work with the InstanceName field in [WmiMonitorID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394542(v=vs.85).aspx) class (EDID structure) that I wanted to read. Don't forget to add setupapi.lib to your Linker > Additional Libraries build setting.

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <wbemidl.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int EnumMonitorIDs()
{
    ret.clear();

    HRESULT hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL; 
    BSTR AbackB = SysAllocString(L"root\\WMI");
    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
         AbackB, // Object path of WMI namespace
         NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
         NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
         0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
         NULL,                    // Security flags.
         0,                       // Authority (e.g. Kerberos)
         0,                       // Context object 
         &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
         );
    SysFreeString(AbackB);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    BSTR wql = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
    BSTR select = SysAllocString(L"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID");
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        wql,
        select,
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
    SysFreeString(wql);
    SysFreeString(select);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = 0;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;   
    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        // ok, we have the EDID record, pull some fields out of it

        VARIANT vtProp;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"InstanceName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            wcout << "----------------" << endl << "InstanceName : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
            VariantClear(&vtProp);
        }       


        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ofek Shilon's blog post, and tweaked to get all the device IDs (manufacturer ID + product ID strings):

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
DWORD dev = 0;  // device index
int id = 1;        // monitor number, as used by Display Properties > Settings

Str DeviceID;

while (EnumDisplayDevices(0, dev, &dd, 0))
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE ddMon;
    ZeroMemory(&ddMon, sizeof(ddMon));
    ddMon.cb = sizeof(ddMon);
    DWORD devMon = 0;

    while (EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, devMon, &ddMon, 0))
    {
        DeviceID.Sprintf("%s", ddMon.DeviceID);
        DeviceID = DeviceID.Slice(8);
        if (DeviceID.Index("\\") > 0)
            DeviceID = DeviceID.Slice(0, DeviceID.Index("\\"));

        printf ("DEVICEID = %s --------\n", DeviceID.utf8());
    }

    devMon++;

    ZeroMemory(&ddMon, sizeof(ddMon));
    ddMon.cb = sizeof(ddMon);
  }

  ZeroMemory(&dd, sizeof(dd));
  dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
  dev++;
}
```

N.B. Str here is a custom string class but should be easy to refactor to use anything.